# Update multirow SQL Server faster

Tags: sql-server

I have table `Number (Id int primary key identity, Value int)`. I want to update 2000 columns `Value` with a null value with another value that does not overlap.

I use while to update

```
DECLARE @i_min INT
SET @i_min = 1

DECLARE @max INT

SELECT @max = COUNT(*) 
FROM Number 
WHERE ((Value IS NULL OR Value =''))

WHILE @i_min <= @max 
BEGIN
    UPDATE b 
    SET b.Value = dbo.func_increase_number 
    FROM 
        (SELECT TOP 1 Value 
         FROM Number a
         WHERE (a.Value IS NULL OR a.Value ='')) b

    SET @i_min = @i_min + 1
```

But it is updating each record and it takes 2 minutes to complete the update and when the number of records increases, the update time increases. Please help me update faster

Comment: is that a complete query ? i don't see the `END` for the `WHILE` loop `BEGIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can also update the column value without using a while loop 
Ex -

```
UPDATE Number
SET Value = dbo.func_increase_number 
FROM 
Number 
WHERE Value IS NULL OR Value =''
```

Check It and tell me if it is working or not